# CSS Image Right of Element

Tags: html, css

Here's the predicament I'm in. I need to style all H1 tags like this image:

[image]

So, what would be the best way to do this? I would prefer not to add to the HTML, and just do it with CSS, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. I've tried adding the dotted image to the background of the `h1` and repeating it, but that of course adds it behind the text as well. I then tried using the `:after` pseudo-element, but I can't get it to repeat and work how I want. Any ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need extra markup for this.

Just add dotted image as a background for H1 and use extra SPAN with solid background color around text.

Answer (score 0):

HTML something like this:

```
<h1>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="dotted"></span>
</h1>
```

Css something like this:

```
.dotted{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom:1px solid dotted;
}
```